# How to use Java/Kotlin to read from localstorage inside a webview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, webview

I am creating an Android app that loads a specific page of my website into a webview. This page writes a specific name/value pair to localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("homeconncode", "testcode");
```

How can I access the name/value pair using Java/Kotlin within the apps code (created with Android Studio)?

Thanks in advance. Chris.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could. Seems that that data is meant to be private to the page/site that writes that. This is analogous to a webpage not being able to read other paegs' cookies or storage.

Comment: This link helped me to learn how to do it. https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview. I understand why security would be a concern but i own and have designed the JS in the webview.